# How do I create a delegate for generic list orderby function?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, delegates

I have a project that is using a generic list of a custom class.  I have this bound to a grid and I am trying to implement sorting on it. (which is working).

I want to clean my code so I don't have to do a check for "asc" and "desc" then call either Orderby or OrderByDescending.  I would rather set a delegate method at the to of the function and just call OrderMethod, which would already be set to the proper OrderBy... Method.

I can't seem to get it working.

Here is the delegate that I've created. (The class is called 'FollowingInfo').

```
private delegate IOrderedEnumerable<FollowingInfo> OrderMethodDelegate<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<FollowingInfo> source, Func<FollowingInfo, string> keySelector);
```

I'm try to set it as such.

```
OrderMethodDelegate OrderMethod = FollowList.OrderBy;
```

But it's not working...in this example FollowList is of type List(FollowingInfo).

The OrderBy method is an extension method of the generic list class and is defined in Enumerable as such.

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector);
```

Any ideas of where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define it as:

```
private delegate IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> Func<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector);
```

You cannot simply override generic method defined in `IEnumerable<T>` with replacing `TSource` parameter. It doesn't know about FollowingInfo class. You can provide your own OrderBy extension method for `IEnumerable<FollowingInfo>` and use that kind of delegate in it.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up going with a different definition.

Comment: private Func<Func<FollowingInfo, object>, IOrderedEnumerable<FollowingInfo>> OrderMethod;